# What are the possible shortcomings of using Arduino on a Raspberry Pi 3 rather than as typically on a desktop or laptop running Windows or Linux?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

Setting up a laboratory for kids and cannot decide on which to run Arduino, a Raspberry-pi which I can use for other maker projects, or a normal computer, like a desktop or laptop? Will I face severe shortcomings when running Arduino on Raspberry Pi (3)?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: The upside of using a pi is likely being able to inexpensively source a number of systems to dedicate and not have to fight with getting the right configuration on a diversity of computers/operating systems that are either 2nd hand from other usage or brought in by participants.  The downside may mean things like greater fragility of a pi setup, and longer build/verify times.  Have to agree that this is off topic.

Comment: Some time has passed since I asked this question, and my experience is that raspberry pi is not the best first choice.